# How to provide an option to edit the record on Mouse right click in datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mouseevent

I have datagrid in WPF c#. I need to provide some facility in datagrid so that if user right clicks on any row/column then some interface(like menu) should be displayed.

That interface will have two options.
1. ADD NEW RECORDS.
2. EDIT CURRENT RECORDS.

If user will click on any of the section, which event will be fired to handle this request.

Below is my datagrid.

```
  <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" Name="dgShowSearching" Sorting="dgShowSearching_Sorting" FrozenColumnCount="7" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                  Value="Bold" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                                         Color="LightBlue" />
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="Collapsed" Header="KeywordD" Width="120" Binding="{Binding KeywordID}"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit Filter" Width="80">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Click="btnEditRecords_Click" Name="btnEditRecords" Content="Edit"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Import Records" Width="90">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Click="Import_Click" Name="btnImportRecords" Content="Import"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Records To Import" Width="120">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox IsReadOnly="False" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=RecordsToImport, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RecordsToImport, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Priority">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox Name="cbPriority"
                                          Width="60"
                                          Height="22"
                                          xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPriority, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,FallbackValue=1}">
                                        <sys:Int32 >1</sys:Int32>
                                        <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
                                        <sys:Int32>3</sys:Int32>
                                        <sys:Int32>4</sys:Int32>
                                        <sys:Int32>5</sys:Int32>
                                        <sys:Int32>6</sys:Int32>
                                        <sys:Int32>7</sys:Int32>
                                        <sys:Int32>8</sys:Int32>
                                        <sys:Int32>9</sys:Int32>
                                        <sys:Int32>10</sys:Int32>
                                    </ComboBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedPriority, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Total Records" Width="100" SortMemberPath="TotalRecords" >
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TotalRecords}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=TotalRecords}" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Records Imported" Width="100" SortMemberPath="TotalRecordsImported">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TotalRecordsImported}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=TotalRecordsImported}" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Status}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Width="120" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Width="120" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="All Words" Width="120" Binding="{Binding WithAllOfTheWords}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Exact Phrase" Width="120" Binding="{Binding WithTheExactPhrase}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="At Least One Word" Width="120" Binding="{Binding WithAtLeastOneOfTheseWords}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Without Word" Width="120" Binding="{Binding WithoutTheWord}"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Exact Date" Width="120" SortMemberPath="ExactDate">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ExactDate, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy'}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=ExactDate}" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Start Date" Width="120" SortMemberPath="StartDate" >
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StartDate, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy'}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=StartDate}" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="End Date" Width="120"  SortMemberPath="EndDate">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EndDate, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy'}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=EndDate}" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Start Year" Width="120" SortMemberPath="StartYears" >
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StartYears}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=StartYears}" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="End Year" Width="120" SortMemberPath="EndYear" >
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EndYear}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=EndYear}" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Width="120" Binding="{Binding CountryName}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="State" Width="120" Binding="{Binding StateName}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Width="120" Binding="{Binding CityName}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Publication" Width="120" Binding="{Binding PublicationName}"/>


                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: will a `ContextMenu` not work?

Comment: Thanks, I have a context menu and on click of menu item I filtered the records of selected row